# Run methods from a Java class through Command Line

Tags: java, command-line, jar

For one of our projects for school, we're asked to create a command-line executable program representing a hypothetical school grades system for teachers. We can use any language we want and I chose to use Java. However, with a Jar file executable, I'm not able to freely use the command line in Linux to use the methods I've created. It only runs through the commands I've written in the Main Java file and then exits. I suppose I can run a scanner but that seems tedious to scan and pick out my variable arguments to pass into methods.
Am I missing something? Or did I make the wrong language choice?

Thanks!

Comment: Your `main` method should have one argument: `args` for that.

Comment: If running the program's entry point (i.e. `public static void main`) is not sufficient, would the JShell REPL meet your needs?

Comment: That said, I think if you've been given an assignment to create an executable program, then it's probably your job to write a `main` method which interacts with the user in the desired way.

Comment: [Minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

You can make an indefinite loop in your main which will get the input from console using BufferedReader (recommended) or Scanner.
Then, you could use a Scanner to tokenize de input and check whether the input corresponds to a command using a switch/case.